# Error in code for download a file(txt) in clasic ASP

Tags: file, asp-classic, download

I have been trying 2 diferent codes this is one:

```
nombre="Prueba.txt"
set stream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
stream.Open
stream.Type = 2 ' binary
stream.LoadFromFile(Server.MapPath("./File/"&nombre))
Response.BinaryWrite(stream.Read)
```

And the other code I'm trying is this :

```
Response.ContentType = "application/x-unknown" ' arbitrary 

FPath = Server.MapPath("./File/"&nombre) 
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" & nombre 

Set adoStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream") 
adoStream.Open() 
adoStream.Type = 1 
adoStream.LoadFromFile(FPath) 
Response.BinaryWrite adoStream.Read() 
adoStream.Close 
Set adoStream = Nothing 

Response.End
```

And I get that it have found a non especificated/defined data type.

Comment: Do you want to download a txt or a jpg? (the title differs from the file name)

Comment: A need to download a txt, my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Giancarlo Solarino: Try this --

```
Option Explicit

Dim sFileName, sFilePath, iFileSize
Dim oFile, oFS, oStream

sFileName = "Prueba.txt"
sFilePath = Server.MapPath("File/" & sFileName)

Set oFS = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If oFS.FileExists(sFilePath) Then
    Set oFile = oFS.GetFile(sFilePath)
    iFileSize = oFile.Size
    Set oFile = Nothing

    Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" & sFileName
    Response.ContentType = "application/download"
    Response.AddHeader "Content-Length", iFileSize

    Set oStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.LoadFromFile sFilePath

    Do While NOT oStream.EOS AND Response.IsClientConnected
        Response.BinaryWrite oStream.Read(1024)
        Response.Flush()
    Loop

    oStream.Close
    Set oStream = Nothing
End If
```

Comment: In my case, I had to reset the position of the stream object before reading from it: oStream.Position = 0 (before the While loop)

Answer (score 0):

I have some working code, that's pretty much the same, but I use `ContentType = "image/jpeg"` and `Response.Flush` at the end.

```
Const adTypeBinary = 1

dim strFileName
strFileName = "archivo.jpg"

dim strFilePath
strFilePath = "C:\temp\" + strFileName

dim objStream
Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Open
objStream.Type = adTypeBinary
objStream.LoadFromFile strFilePath

Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & strFileName
Response.Charset = "UTF-8"
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"

Response.BinaryWrite objStream.Read
Response.Flush
```

Comment: It worked well, but the thing is that insted of open a dialog box for downloading the file, ot opens the .txt in the browser. You have any idea how can I get a dialog box?? Thanks.

Comment: Supposedly `Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & strFileName` force the browsed to show the download dialog, but it depends on the browser and user configuration. It's the best you can do.